# Как решить ожерелье пазл?

Tags: python, алгоритм, матрицы, constraints

Здесь условия пазла. Описание [головоломки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5_(%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0))
Надо решить с помощью `python constraint`. Я написал код. Когда пишу `getSolution` он выводить самый первый вариант. Когда я хочу посмотреть на весь вариант, долго работает даже на 3x3 матрице.

```
all_line_chars = ["│","─","└","┘","┌","┐","."]
black_chars = ["└","┘","┌","┐"]
white_chars = ["│","─"]
not_turn_chars = ["│","─","."]
left_edge = [".","│","└","┌"]
right_edge = [".","│","┐","┘"]
up_edge = [".","─","┐","┌"]
down_edge = [".","─","└","┘"]

def init_cons(ms,p):
    sz = len(p)
    for i in range(sz):
        t1 = (i,0)
        ms.addConstraint(InSetConstraint(left_edge), [t1])
        t2 = (0,i)
        ms.addConstraint(InSetConstraint(up_edge), [t2])
        t3 = (sz-1,i)
        ms.addConstraint(InSetConstraint(down_edge), [t3])
        t4 = (i,sz-1)
        ms.addConstraint(InSetConstraint(right_edge), [t4])

    for i in range(sz):
        for j in range(sz):
            o = p[i][j]
            t = (i,j)
            s1 = (i - 1, j)
            s2 = (i, j - 1)
            s3 = (i + 1, j)
            s4 = (i, j + 1)
            if o == "┼":
                ms.addConstraint(SomeInSetConstraint(black_chars), [t])
                if i - 1 >= 0:
                    ms.addConstraint(SomeInSetConstraint(not_turn_chars), [s1])
                if j - 1 >= 0:
                    ms.addConstraint(SomeInSetConstraint(not_turn_chars), [s2])
                if i + 1 <= sz - 1:
                    ms.addConstraint(SomeInSetConstraint(not_turn_chars), [s3])
                if j + 1 <= sz - 1:
                    ms.addConstraint(SomeInSetConstraint(not_turn_chars), [s4])
            if o == "╬":
                ms.addConstraint(SomeInSetConstraint(white_chars), [t])
```